# Change locale for django-admin-tools

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-admin, django-admin-tools

In my `settings.py` file I have:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-RU'
```

also, I have installed and working django-admin-tools. But admin language still english. What I'm doing wrong?

PS.

```
$ cat settings.py | grep USE | grep -v USER
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set the language specifically for the admin app. Since django does not provide a language drop down as part of the default login, you have a few options:

1. Login to your normal (non admin view), with superuser/staff credentials and the correct language, then shift over to the admin URL.
2. Update the admin templates and add a language dropdown [see this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/751/).
3. Create some custom middleware to set the language for admin:

   ```
   from django.conf import settings
   from django.utils import translation

   class AdminLocaleMiddleware:

       def process_request(self, request):
           if request.path.startswith('/admin'):
               request.LANG = getattr(settings, 'ADMIN_LANGUAGE_CODE',
                                      settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
               translation.activate(request.LANG)
               request.LANGUAGE_CODE = request.LANG
   ```

   Add it to your [`MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#middleware-classes)

   ```
   MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = {
       # ...
       'foo.bar.AdminLocaleMiddleware',
       # ...
   }
   ```

   Set the language you want for the admin in `settings.py`:

   ```
   ADMIN_LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-RU'
   ```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm trying your [3] and I can't manage to include the Middleware, where do you place the file?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have translation and localization enabled in your `settings.py`:

```
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
```

Also check if you have the translation file (`.mo`, `.po`) for russian.

Comment: Yes, I'm has these lines. .mo and .po files exists in site-packages.