# Wrong language in django admin

Tags: django, django-i18n, django-rosetta

Why is `django.contrib.admin` in English even though I set `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pl'` in the settings?

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pl'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Warsaw'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('pl', _('Polish')),
)
```

Deleting `('en', _('English')),` from `LANGUAGES` helps but I need it from [django-rosetta](https://github.com/mbi/django-rosetta/).

Thank you.

Comment: Have you updated your `urls.py`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change locale for django-admin-tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177330/change-locale-for-django-admin-tools)

Comment: I dont think this is a duplicate, when i delete LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('pl', _('Polish')),
) django admin is translated to polish

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469470/how-can-i-change-django-admin-language

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177330/change-locale-for-django-admin-tools

Answer (score 3):

This function can be used in your root URLconf and Django will automatically prepend the current active language code to all url patterns defined within [i18n_patterns()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#language-prefix-in-url-patterns)

```
  urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Source:
[How can I change Django admin language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469470/how-can-i-change-django-admin-language)

Comment: okay but why i get redirected to http://localhost:8000/en/admin/ even though I set LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pl' in settings?

Comment: user logged in django admin needs to see it in polish by default

Comment: Have you gone through the above mentioned  links.Y not you create a language drop down http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177330/change-locale-for-django-admin-tools(if required)

Comment: I dont think you get it, it maybe because of my bad english. Ive gone through all the links above but none solves my problem. I dont want drop down to choose between polish and english in django admin. It just needs to be in polish by default.

Comment: I tested by changing the language to LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-RU'.And django admin panel by default converted into russian.And did the same for polish language too LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pl'.It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this in your settings file.I tested it and works fine.

```
 LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pl'
```

When user logged in django admin needs it shows polish by default.Some words are shown in english.
Still problem is not solved share the screen shot of the django admin.